# How to draw trend line for different type of data in R?

Tags: r, plot

Here is my data:

```
> est_mean
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] 17.317 15.529 11.650 14.044 15.681 14.665
[2,] 19.130 17.342 13.463 15.857 17.494 16.478

> ob_mean_non_ed
       0        1        2        3        4        5 
17.68966 15.13793 11.24138 14.58621 15.06897 16.65517 
> ob_mean_ed
       0        1        2        3        4        5 
18.83784 17.64865 13.78378 15.43243 17.97297 14.91892
```

I'm trying to draw a trend line using the `est_mean` data, and superimpose the `ob_mean_non_ed` and `Ob_mean_ed` data. So there will be 4 lines in one plot, two for `est_mean` and the other two for `ob_mean_*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ggplot2` to draw lines by groups. Is this what you want?

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(
  variable = rep(c("est_mean1", "est_mean2", "ob_mean_ed", "ob_mean_non_ed"), each = 6L), 
  x = rep(0:5, 4L), 
  y = c(t(est_mean), ob_mean_ed, ob_mean_non_ed)
)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, group = variable, color = variable)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, group = variable, color = variable)) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank())
```

Output

[image]